# Rails / ActiveRecord: detect if a column is an association or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming I am abstracting code, and am looping through the column names of object x, what's the best way to detect if a column is an association or not?

I know I can do this, but I am wondering if there is a better way:

```
@user = User.first
  @user.attributes.keys.each do |column|
    if column[-3..-1] == "_id" && @user.respond_to?(column[0..-4].to_sym)
      puts "#{column} is an association / relation."
    else
      puts "#{column} is not an assocation / relation."
    end
  end
end
```

Any built-in Rails methods or helpers to detect associations? Code above is neither pretty nor fool proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do this would be to reflect upon all associations for that class:

```
associations = class_goes_here.reflect_on_all_associations
```

And then to find just the `belongs_to` ones, since those will have the `_id` field:

```
associations = associations.select { |a| a.macro == :belongs_to }
```

Then you can find the foreign key used on these associations by doing this:

```
association_foreign_keys = associations.map(&:foreign_key)
```

I wouldn't use `@user.attributes` to get the attributes and then `keys` on that to get the column names. I would use `User.column_names` to get the column names.

Therefore, with all that explained, you can then change your code to be this to make it more foolproof:

```
associations = User.reflect_on_all_associations
associations = associations.select { |a| a.macro == :belongs_to }
association_foreign_keys = associations.map(&:foreign_key)
User.column_names.each do |column|
  if association_foreign_keys.include?(column)
    puts "#{column} is an association / relation."
  else
    puts "#{column} is not an assocation / relation."
  end
end
```

Comment: As of Rails 1.1.1 you can filter by macro immediately: `associations = User.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)` and save the second line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that selected solution is better, but if you live in "ideal world", where everybody follow the rails convention, I suppose you can rely on [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html):

> **2.2** Schema Conventions Active Record uses naming conventions for the
>   columns in database tables, depending on the purpose of these columns.
>
> Foreign keys - These fields should be named following the pattern
>   singularized_table_name_id (e.g., item_id, order_id). These are the
>   fields that Active Record will look for when you create associations
>   between your models.

So just look for _id suffix at the end of column name:

```ruby
Model.column_names.select{|cn| cn.include?("_id")}
```

Comment: I personally think it's a error-prone approach since people (unfortunately) break those convention rules..

Comment: That's why I mentioned conventions.